# Bootstrap gradient mixin not working in IE9

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9, gradient

I have this code that I got from compiling a bootstrap gradient less mixin:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(108, 91, 123, 0.8) 0%, rgba(53, 92, 125, 0.8) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(108, 91, 123, 0.8) 0%, rgba(53, 92, 125, 0.8) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(108, 91, 123, 0.8) 0%, rgba(53, 92, 125, 0.8) 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cc6c5b7b', endColorstr='#cc355c7d', GradientType=0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzyfg67z/

It works OK in all major browsers, IE 10+ too, but not in IE9.

**I wonder if Bootstrap gradient mixins are supposed to be supported at all by IE9, or is something with my code?**

Comment: Check out http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ they have a special checkbox for IE9 support gradients, but it looks like it is achieved using SVG

Answer (score 1):

Background gradients in IE9 I don't think is supported. The workaround seems to be using SVG as outlined in this [approach](http://css3wizardry.com/2010/10/29/css-gradients-for-ie9/).